# Azure AD B2C External Identity for Consumer Accounts

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm currently setting up Azure B2C tenancy. As part of the setup, I'm integrating with external identities for the User to login. However, the requirement I have is that once signed-in using their external identities I want a corresponding user record to be created in my tenancy which I want to use later for application-specific role management & fine-grain access.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Thanks @Techwiz and you can use audit log or azure monitor or usage analytics. Please refer document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/view-audit-logs.

Answer (score 0):

The described behavior is default and only supported one, for Azure AD B2C.

Once a user signs-in with their social identity provider, a "local" profile will be created - indicating basic info, like which social IDP the user is using, any info provided by the provider, any additional info that you explicitly required from the user (via `user attributes`).

You can later use this "local profile" for manage user's info. Here is an example of such user profiles in a B2C tenant:

[image]

You see some users coming from Gmail, some from Facebook, some from "other" (which is actually Microsoft365 in my case).